# Building a Vlookup between separate workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, vlookup

I am new to VBA coding and am attempting to build a Vlookup to connect two seperate workbooks. Provided belwo is my coding which is currently producing a Run-Time 1004 Method 'Range' of Object'_Global' Failed error on the vlookup line.

```
Sub dataEntry(agent As Integer, month As Integer)

Dim lookupReturn As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lookupValue As String
Dim lookupBook As String

i = 1
'set excel book to preform vlookup within
lookupBook = sheetName & "-Daily Report Daily-Monthly Grid.xlsx"

'Preforms a Vlookup to fill in data points
Do While Workbooks("Cumulative Agent Ranking Template").Sheets(sheetName).Cells(i,     1).Value <> ""
    lookupValue = Workbooks("Cumulative Agent Ranking Template").Sheets(sheetName).Cells(i, 10).Value
    lookupReturn = Sheets(sheetName).WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C2"), [lookupBook] & sheet33 & Range("!$A$2" & ":$C" & agent), 2, False)
    Workbooks("Cumulative Agent Ranking Template").Sheets(sheetName).Cells(i, 11).Value = lookupReturn
    i = i + 1
    lookupValue = ""
    lookupReturn = 0
Loop
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my answer? Is it working for you? If so, please mark it as accepted so that others may benefit from this Q & A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are probably a lot of things going wrong here.

Let's start with the most obvious source of 1004 error, which is unqualified range objects.

**Example:** in a standard module, `Range("C2")` always refers to the Active sheet. In a sheet module, it always refers to the parent sheet.

**To Resolve:** fully qualify your range variables, e.g., `Workbooks(_name_).Worksheets(_sheetname_).Range("C2")`

Another potential problem I notice is the way you're calling the `Vlookup`.

`Sheets(sheetName).WorksheetFunction...`

There is no such method `WorksheetFunction` of a worksheet object.  This is an application-level method, so invoke it like:

`WorksheetFunction.Vlookup...`

**Additional problems or potential problems**

Undeclared variables: `sheetname`  (maybe this is a public or module-level variable?)

Unused variables: `lookupValue`  You've declared this, and you've assigned to it, but you haven't *done* anything to it or used it anywhere else in the code.  **is this the value you're trying to *search* for?**

The rest of your formula is also pretty gnarly and I'm not even going to try and fix it in its current state.  If you use better-defined object variables, your code will be easier to read and understand.  You will also benefit from intellisense if the variables are strongly typed in declaration.

Here is an example, which I will leave up to you to work out for your own needs:

```
Dim lookupBook as Workbook
Dim lookupRange as Range
Dim lookupValue as String

Set lookupBook = Workbooks("some other file.xlsx")
Set lookupRange = lookupBook.Worksheets("some worksheet").Range("A1:B50")
lookupValue = "cat"

Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(lookupValue, lookupRange, 2, False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and as you can see I am very "green" when it comes to VBA. I did change my coding to be more like the example; however, the problem I am running into is that each month the workbook I will be searching in changes. I attempted to use a variable to call the workbook. This is what I came up with but it is not working. Set lookupBook = Workbooks(sheetName & "-Daily Report Daily-Monthly Grid.xlsx")... sheetName contains a prefix that is specific to each new file created monthly.

Comment: Is the requested workbook already open? (If yes, then you have mis-spelled something; if no, then you have to open it first).  You can do that with `Workbooks.Open(_full_path_to_file_)` statement.